# Stochastic integration with python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I want to numerically solve integrals that contain white noise.

Mathematically white noise can be described by a variable `X(t)`, which is a random variable with a time average, `Avg[X(t)] = 0` and the correlation function, `Avg[X(t), X(t')] = delta_distribution(t-t')`.

A simple example would be to calculate the integral over `X(t)` from `t=0` to `t=1`. On average this is of course zero, but what I need are different realizations of this integral.

The problem is that this does not work with `numpy.integrate.quad()`.

Are there any packages for `python` that deal with stochastic integrals?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199574/simulating-a-stochastic-integral. If this does not help, stats.stackexchange would still be a better place to ask.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your problem is? Why is quad() insufficient? I realize that it usually assumes something about the smoothness of the function you're integrating, but it seems like the accuracy of the results would depend heavily on the magnitude of the function relative to the noise. Why can't you for example just compute a finite integral with `np.trapz()`?

Comment: I believe what I wanted to ask back then is clarified in the link that rocksportrocker posted. However, I cannot delete or edit my question anymore...

Answer (score 4):

This is a good starting point for numerical SDE methods: http://math.gmu.edu/~tsauer/pre/sde.pdf.

Here is a simple numpy solver for the stochastic differential equation `dX_t = a(t,X_t)dt + b(t,X_t)dW_t` which I wrote for a class project last year. It is based on the forward euler method for regular differential equations, and in practice is fairly widely used when solving SDEs.

```
def euler_maruyama(a,b,x0,t):
    N = len(t)
    x = np.zeros((N,len(x0)))
    x[0] = x0
    for i in range(N-1):
        dt = t[i+1]-t[i]
        dWt = np.random.normal(0,dt)
        x[i+1] = x[i] + a(t[i],x[i])*dt + b(t[i],x[i])*dWt
    return x
```

Essentially, at each timestep, the deterministic part of the function is integrated using forward Euler, and the stochastic part is integrated by generating a normal random variable `dWt` with mean 0 and variance `dt` and integrating the stochastic part with respect to this.

The reason we generate `dWt` like this is based on the definition of Brownian motions. In particular, if $W$ is a Brownian motion, then $(W_t-W_s)$ is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $t-s$. So `dWt` is a discritization of the change in $W$ over a small time interval.

This is a the docstring from the function above:

```
Parameters
----------
a : callable a(t,X_t),
    t is scalar time and X_t is vector position
b : callable b(t,X_t),
    where t is scalar time and X_t is vector position
x0 : ndarray
    the initial position
t : ndarray
    list of times at which to evaluate trajectory

Returns
-------
x : ndarray
    positions of trajectory at each time in t
```